# Nginx modify Cookie domain

Tags: nginx, cookies

Is it possible to modify the cookie domain with NGINX?

I have a black box application on the `sso.example.com` domain. It sets up the `KEYCLOAK_SESSION` cookie with the `sso.example.com` domain.

I need to be able to access this cookie from the `example.com` domain as well. That's why I'm considering modifying the cookie domain with NGINX on the fly. Is it possible to implement this? If so, could you please show how?